# Node.js async.mapSeries for a JSON with array of 2000 objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, mongoose

I create a server Nodejs.
I receive an json of 2000 array object like:

```
{[object1, object2..., object2000]}
```

I used async.mapSeries for iterator in the req.body like

```
 async.mapSeries(req.body, function iterator(item, cb) { },function done(error,datas){
        console.log(datas);
        res.json(error ? { message: + error } : datas);
```

It works, but **my server take 8minutes for finishing!!!**
Anyone know if there is another way to do that?
I used mongodb atlas for my database

Thank you

Comment: you should mention what exactly are you doing with the data

Comment: Is the 8 minutes the total time taken to a) receive the data; b) process the data; and c) send the response? Or is that 8 minutes just the time taken by the async.mapSeries? i.e. what exactly are you timing?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not clear! 8 minutes for process the data.
When the server receive JSON, it take 8 minutes for process data

Comment: The question is incomplete:
1. We don't known the nature of data (maybe the objects are enormous and only the JSON marshalling/unmarshalling can take a lot of time).
2. You use async.mapSeries that proces one thing at time.
3. Remember that node.js is single thread.
4. The information about the database is completely useless without context.